# Angular JS Dependent Form Field Validations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have to implement validation in angular js. The requirement is, there is a form containing an input field which can contain only 9 digits.Below that input field there are three radio buttons. Now, upon form submission, i have to check whether the input field is valid(containing 9 digits) if the user has entered data into the input field and also if the user has not entered any data into the input field, a validation message should appear instructing the user to select any one of the below options(radio buttons).Since am a novice in angularjs , can someone tell me how should i implement this in angularjs.

Example Code :

```
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" id="someNumber" name="someNumber" ng-maxlength="9" ng-model="vm.someFileNumber">
If you don't have SomeNumber, then please answer the following
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.option1">
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.option2">
<input type="radio" ng-model="vm.option3">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set common name to your radio-buttons and set attribute ng-required="!vm.someFileNumber" to one of them